# Kill twice called function and reload once onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The function below is starting if page is loaded. To load other images I need to kill that function and reload it. The way below is loaded the function twice, thats why need to kill and call.

I know that ajaxComplete is the reason for the second call but could not find a way to kill the ready and reload the function onclick.

```
function imageGallery() {
    $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
        gallery:true,
        item:1,
        loop:false
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    imageGallery();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    imageGallery();
});
```

Comment: Oh God! Missing the right keywords to search.. Thanks a lot @Martijn

Comment: It's quite often called 'destroy()'